# Soil microbiology reference

Tags: microbiology, ecology, literature, book-recommendation, soil

I am after some good reference on Soil Microbe Ecology and Biology. I am a biophysicist, and have read the very gentle approach of "Life in the Soil" (James Nardi). Another book I have been recommended is "Soil Microorganisms and Higher Plants: The Classic Text on Living Soils" by Krasil'nikov. This I found very hard going and I was wondering if there was anything more modern on the same subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, looking for books tends to be very opinion-based, and thus is typically not a good match for this site.

Comment: what would a good site/platform be for this?

Comment: Research Gate  might be a good place to post a question like this. It might also help if you provided a little more context about your specific interests re: soil microbiology. It's a broad, interdisciplinary field that has many overlapping themes with agricultural applications, biotechnology, conservation, bioremediation, environmental toxicology, epidemiology and public health, theoretical ecology and evolution, and even astrobiology. It's good to build a broad knowledge base when starting to learn a new subject, but it can still help to narrow your focus just a bit.